# Can ArcGIS service pack be uninstalled at 10.1?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, installation

At v10, it was nice that you [could roll back individual Service Packs.](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/38511)

[image]

Ive just rolled forward to 10.1 SP1 on my dev machine (not a fresh install), but it would appear this option is not available at 10.1.

**Anyone know of a way to roll back the Service Pack without having to do a re-install?**

[image]

EDIT - As an Esri distributor employee I have an pre-release of SP1, and I assumed it was the same final version that would be made available to clients.

I would like to suggest leaving this Q open until the final release is made available, and I will re-test and either edit my Q accordingly, or vote to close the Q off if its not an issue anymore.  Apologies if I have caused any confusion.  I can say that there is some nice new stuff to play with in this SP :)

Comment: Has 10.1 SP1 been made available yet?

Comment: I have to second @polygeo. It doesn't look like SP1 for 10.1 has been released officially yet. I can't imagine this is functionality they would remove. I could believe it is something they wait to add until right before release.

Comment: This Service Pack is due in the next two days. http://support.esri.com/en/downloads/patches-servicepacks/view/productid/160/metaid/1898

Comment: Did you `apply` the patch on top of 10.1, or uninstall 10.1 then install 10.1 SP1?

Comment: On top of 10.1.

Comment: @Simon, What version number do you have with the service pack? On Desktop, I have 10.1.1.3143.

Comment: The Desktop, Engine, Server, and ArcSDE service pack 1 for 10.1 are now available: http://support.esri.com/en/downloads/patches-servicepacks

Comment: @mkennedy  Hmm, thats the sme version number I have as well for Desktop, Server & Web Adapter.  Not sure if this helps, but the file is called ArcGIS_Server_for_Windows_101sp1_132827.exe and was created on 26/10/12

Comment: @Simon, the file name is the same, but the version I have access to has a date of 23 oct on the file property page.

Comment: With 10.1 SP1, Desktop SP1 = msp (patch) and Server SP1 = msi (full installer). I dont know 100% if that means you cant roll back, but I'd guess thats the case for SERVER. See the install notes here: http://support.esri.com/en/downloads/patches-servicepacks/view/productid/189/metaid/1913  In short, with SP1, Desktop IS different than Server in terms of how you install the SP

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think I can say that this is the 'official' 10.1 SP1 install because it hasn't been released yet. It is what I've been certifying my area of the software with.

[image: A screenshot of an XP machine with ArcGIS for Desktop 10.1 SP1 installed]

Std Disclaimer: Although I work for Esri, this should not be considered an official statement from the company.

Comment: Agreed with @mkennedy - this option is available, but 10.1 SP1 has not been released yet. (ya I'm an Esri employee)

Comment: Thanks for this, great to see Esri chipping in on here.  Might well be the SP I have will differ to final release.  See my edited Q.